# How can I get a string that contains all the selected items in a multiselectlist?

Tags: c#, linq, razor, multi-select

In my view I have my model that has a multiselectlist "YogaStyles". I can get the selected items by index with ".SelectedValues" and a list of all the items in the list with ".Items", where each item has a id and a value that shows the name in the list.

How can I match up the selected values with the items so that I can return a string that shows all the selected items in a string ex. "ashtanga, bikram, anazazi"

here is my model and I'm trying to do it in razor syntax

```
 @{
     var values = Model.YogaStyles.SelectedValues;
     var items = Model.YogaStyles.Items;

  }
```

Comment: Foreach over the selected values and perform string concatenation?

Answer (score 0):

```
var listOfValues = string.Join(", ", Model.YogaStyles.SelectedValues.Select(x => x.Name)
                                                                    .ToArray());
```

Comment: there's no .select on selectedvalues!

Comment: I made the assumption that it was an IEnumerable of some sort and could be Linq-ed upon. What is SelectedValues?

Comment: selectedvalues is an ienumerable, but there is no select I can use on it

Comment: this seems like it should be easy. I have a multiselectlist with some selected values and I just want to get the values/names of those selected values in my view. I want to put them in a list or string or something, doesn't really matter what!

Comment: .Select is a LINQ method that can be used on any enumiration. You will need System.Linq referenced.

Comment: I'm doing this in razor syntax in my view! where would I add the linq namespace?